# Unambiguous alternatives for "more/less granular" for data?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

In the usage notes for "[granular](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/granular)" on Wiktionary, it points out that depending on context "more granular" could mean "bigger grains", i.e. coarser, or "smaller grains", i.e. finer.

The term "[granular data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Granularity)" refers to data that has been broken down into small components, for example separating one variable (like a street address) into multiple components (such as state, county, street, etc). The Wikipedia article calls the former "coarse granularity" and the latter "fine[r] granularity".

What, then, is the suitable way to refer to how granular these are in relation to each other, as an adjective? "Coarsely granular" and "finely granular" make sense but sound a bit awkward, especially when I add superlatives like "more coarsely granular", and a lot of the alternatives I can think of are similarly cumbersome, like "data with a finer level of detail".

My natural instinct is to say that the data that has finer granularity is "more granular", but I'm worried about the ambiguity. What is the alternative if I want to be concise but also unambiguous?

For example:

- This algorithm is designed to operate on [more granular] data. You will need to split the variables into components before applying it.

Comment: Granularity is built on the concept of the sieve. Real physical granularity uses 3-dimensional sieves and filters and screens to control for physical size of the grains. Metaphorical granularity uses metaphorical filters (often called "filters", in fact, like Unix utilities). These can be anything that engages the senses that do the filtering, like louder/softer sounds, black-white/colored images, or any other filter set like pH. "Granular" works for all of them as long as you don't take the metaphor literally.

Comment: What's wrong with simply using "coarser" and "finer"?

Comment: In your example, could you say "granulated data"? That would also indicate that the user would need to granulate that data before applying it

Comment: Can you explain how 'more granular' could mean 'bigger grains'? Don't you think we must start out with a single lump of stuff, and break it down into grains… which necessarily makes 'more granular' mean 'smaller grains'?

Comment: I assume it's because if the grains are fine enough then they don't even register as individual grains, so being more granular means the grains are more evident.